# How to troubleshoot and get fopen()to work in php5?

Tags: php, file, fopen

I've searched as hard as I can, and have been stuck on what seems like such a simple issue.

I'm trying to use `fopen()` in php to create a simple txt file. My code is as follows:

`$myfile = fopen("text.txt", "w") or die("Not Working");`

But No matter what I've tried it won't work.

I use Godaddy hosting; plesk on windows.

`allow_url_open` is on.
and `open_basedir` is set to `none`.

I've confirmed this with `phpinfo()`.

I read somewhere that `perror` can be used, I've tried using it in this context and it doesn't output anything:

`$myfile = fopen("text.txt", "w") or perror("error");`

I have `display_errors` set to `on`.

I'm really racking my brain on what else to try. GoDaddy support was useless.

Any advise on troubleshooting or what else my problem could be based off this information would be very helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: You're missing a closing double quote around `text.txt`

Comment: Thanks. But the actual code has them. My bad for not copy pasting.

Comment: Try [error_get_last()](http://php.net/error_get_last). `display_errors` by itself won't help if `error_reporting` has been set wrong.

Comment: File system permissions are ok?